# Tagging Beanstalk environments created with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

When creating an Elastic Beanstalk environment using Cloud Formation, how do you set the Tags allocated to the environment and instances?

For example I have the following Resource definition:

```
"BeanstalkEnvironment" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
  "Properties" : {
    "ApplicationName" : { "Ref" : "BeanstalkApplication" },
     "Description" :  "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Demo Application",
     "SolutionStackName" : "64bit Windows Server 2012 R2 running IIS 8.5",
     "EnvironmentName" : "Test Site",
     "CNAMEPrefix" : { "Ref" : "URLPrefix" },
     "OptionSettings" : [
       {"Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration", "OptionName" : "EC2KeyName", "Value" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" }},
       {"Namespace" : "aws:ec2:vpc", "OptionName" : "VPCId", "Value" : { "Ref" : "VPC" }},
       {"Namespace" : "aws:ec2:vpc", "OptionName" : "Subnets", "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : [ ",", [ { "Ref" : "SubnetA" }, { "Ref" : "SubnetB" }, { "Ref" : "SubnetC" } ] ] } },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:ec2:vpc", "OptionName" : "ELBSubnets", "Value" : { "Fn::Join" : [ ",", [ { "Ref" : "SubnetA" }, { "Ref" : "SubnetB" }, { "Ref" : "SubnetC" } ] ] } },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration", "OptionName":"InstanceType", "Value" : "t2.micro" },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:ec2:vpc", "OptionName":"AssociatePublicIpAddress", "Value":"true" },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate", "OptionName":"MaxBatchSize", "Value": "1" },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate", "OptionName":"MinInstancesInService", "Value": "1" },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate", "OptionName":"PauseTime", "Value": "PT5M30S" },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:autoscaling:updatepolicy:rollingupdate", "OptionName":"RollingUpdateEnabled", "Value": "true" },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:elasticbeanstalk:command", "OptionName":"BatchSize", "Value": "30" },
       {"Namespace" : "aws:elb:policies", "OptionName":"ConnectionDrainingEnabled", "Value": "true" }
      ],
     "VersionLabel" : "Sample .NET Application"
    }
  }
```

A full working example template is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rhysgodfrey/577e11acb0f34f7c1ee4).

And would like to add a set of Tags to the Beanstalk and the instances it creates e.g.:

```
"Tags" : [ 
          { "Key" : "Contact", "Value" : { "Ref" : "Contact" } },
          { "Key" : "BudgetCode", "Value" : { "Ref" : "BudgetCode" } } 
        ]
```

There does not appear to be a "Tags" element for the [Elastic Beanstalk Resource Type](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html) in the same way there is for other types (e.g. [S3 Buckets](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket.html#cfn-s3-bucket-tags)).

Any suggestions on how to do this? Would be really good to ensure the instances created are correctly tagged so we can track what instances are used for different projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example given in the OP should now work.

AWS added support for tagging Elastic Beanstalk Environments on 08/24/2015:
http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/08/aws-cloudformation-updates-support-for-amazon-vpc-aws-lambda-aws-elastic-beanstalk-amazon-rds-and-amazon-s3/

Usage is the same as other CFN resource types that support tags - include a Tags key in the Properties mapping and assign a list of Key, Value mappings:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html#cfn-beanstalk-environment-tags

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had the answer, but instead I have the same problem.  You can do this in the create environment cli and in the api, but there doesn't seem to be a namespace for this in the options settings for doing it in a cloudformation template.  (At least it's not a documented namespace from what I can see).  My google-fu doesn't show anyone else with an answer to this yet either.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and Amazon support has indicated that it is a gap in functionality.